# Toolbar icons unable to load when running Emacs through xhost from FreeBSD to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, freebsd, emacs, gtk

I'm connected to a FreeBSD Computer using `ssh [ip] -X`, and emacs launches just fine, but this happens and all the icons are little pieces of paper with red X's:

```
> emacs

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-new' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-open' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'image-missing' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'window-close' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-save' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-undo' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-cut' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-copy' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-paste' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-find' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening? GVIM loads just fine.

Comment: It's related absolotely to your FreeBSD system... Do you have X on FreeBSD? Do you have some dependendies on your FreeBSD? Sure dependencies of gvim difffer with gemacs.

Comment: @PersianGulf It does have X, and Emacs runs fine there.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there could be a matter of the GTK configuration on the machine where Emacs is running? Someone at the Qt Centre forums has discovered what appears to present a resolution for a similar warning from the GdkPixbuf lib, when it's linked with the Qt widget toolkit [[Qt Centre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35092-QT-4-7-GdkPixbuf-WARNING-**-Bug!-loader-png-didn-t-set-an-error-on-failure)]

The article would seem to recommend to run, as the root user on the machine where Emacs is running:

```
update-mime /usr/share/mime/
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime/
gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/<ThemeName>
```

Personally, I would like to assume that those shell commands could be run during package post-installation scripts, on Ubuntu. Maybe that's already a feature, though. There is a [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gtk-update-icon-cache.1.html) available for the `gtk-update-icon-cache` shell command, on Ubuntu.

Alternately, might it be possible to build Emacs without GTK? The Debian *[maint-guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/)* provides documentation about the  `debian/rules` file and the Debian `debuild` command, in building Debian packages from source. The source packages on a Debian type distro can be retrieved with `apt-get` [[BuildingTutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial)] At the Emacs Wiki, there's also documentation about building Emacs from source code [[BuildingEmacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildingEmacs)]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have the PNG's for those icons installed on your FreeBSD system. Specifically, the ones I have in my FreeBSD 10 system (which works fine with ssh -X) are:

```
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/document-new.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/document-open.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/document-save.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/edit-copy.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/edit-cut.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/edit-find.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/edit-paste.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/edit-undo.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/actions/window-close.png
/usr/local/share/icons/gnome/24x24/apps/system-file-manager.png
```

The initial path may be different so I'd do a `locate` on the basename, e.g. `locate edit-find.png`.

Also, do a `truss -o /tmp/truss.out emacs` and quit as soon as you get into that. Then run:

```
grep 'png"' /tmp/truss.out
```

and it should show you if you are finding the pngs or not. If not, those files belong to gnome-icon-theme-3.6.2, so install that possibly adjusting the version number.

Comment: It runs fine on the FreeBSD system itself, but I'll look next chance I get.

Comment: The bounty will expire before I get a chance to look, but if you're right, I'll reinstate it then mark you as correct.

Comment: If it runs fine on the FreeBSD system itself, then I wonder if the problem is that the pngs arent around on the system you are ssh'ing from. I think the clearest indicator would be to compare truss output from the setup that works with the setup that doesn't.

Comment: I tried copying the entire theme from one system to the other, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Post the output  of running the *grep* command after gathering output with the *truss* command.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PUszMiLX

Comment: @AidanEdwards ok, it looks like emacs is finding the pngs that you just copied and presumably weren't there before. These files belong to the package gnome-icon-theme-3.6.2 so see if you have that installed (possibly the 3.6.3 is different), and if not install them.

Comment: I installed gnome-icon-theme from APT in Ubuntu and restarted, but nothing is different.

Comment: You need to install it on the FreeBSD system, not on Ubuntu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25626/discussion-between-aidan-edwards-and-rocky).